# SSH ProxyJump applies wrong username

Tags: ssh, openssh

Given the following `ssh.cfg`:

```
Host bastion
  Hostname xx.yyy.169.100
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ./the-key.pem

Host 10.250.*.*
  ProxyJump %r@bastion
  User core
  IdentityFile ./the-key.pem
```

The attempt to connect to the server via the `bastion` is failing, because ssh applies wrong username:

```
$ ssh -vvF ssh.cfg 10.250.198.76
...
debug1: Reading configuration data ssh.cfg
debug1: ssh.cfg line 1: Applying options for bastion
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xx.yyy.169.100 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xx.yyy.169.100 [xx.yyy.169.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ./the-key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file ./the-key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xx.yyy.169.100:22 as 'core'
...
```

I expected that ssh will apply the `ubuntu` user when it's connecting to the bastion and will only apply `core` user when it's connecting to the target server.

Is there a way to configure it the way I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%r` part of your `ProxyJump` entry is being substituted for the username of the remote machine you are currently trying to ssh into (`core`). You just need:

`ProxyJump bastion`

so that it uses the default username for your `bastion` entry. See the [OpenSSH Cookbook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH%2FCookbook%2FProxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Passing_Through_One_or_More_Gateways_Using_ProxyJump) for more information.